# Disposing pointers to complex records

Tags: delphi, pointers, dispose

I have list of pointers to some complex records. Sometimes when I try disposing them I get invalid pointer operation error. I'm not really sure if I'm creating and disposing them properly.
The record looks like this:

```
type
  PFILEDATA = ^TFILEDATA;
  TFILEDATA = record
    Description80: TFileType80;  // that's array[0..80] of WideChar
    pFullPath: PVeryLongPath;    // this is pointer to array of WideChar
    pNext: PFILEDATA;            // this is pointer to the next TFILEDATA record
  end;
```

As I understand when I want a pointer to such record I need to initialize the pointer and the dynamic arrays like this:

```
function GimmeNewData(): PFILEDATA;
begin
  New(Result);
  New(Result^.pFullPath);
end;
```

Now to dispose of series of these records I wrote this:

```
procedure DisposeData(var pData: PFILEDATA);
var pNextData: PFILEDATA;
begin
  while pData^.pNext <> nil do begin
    pNextData := pData^.pNext;          // Save pointer to the next record
    Finalize(pData^.pFullPath);         // Free dynamic array
    Dispose(pData);                     // Free the record
    pData := pNextData;
  end;
  Finalize(pData^.pFullPath);
  Dispose(pData);
  pData := nil;
end;
```

When I run my program in the debug mode (F9) in the Delphi 2010 IDE something weird happens. When I step trough DisposeData code with F8 it appears that program skips Finalize(pData^.pFullPath) line and jumps to Dispose(pData). Is this normal? Also when Dispose(pData) is executed the Local variables window that displays contents of the pointers does not change. Does this mean that dispose fails?

Edit:
PVeryLongPath is:

```
type
  TVeryLongPath = array of WideChar;
  PVeryLongPath = ^TVeryLongPath;
```

Edit2

So I create 2 TFILEDATA records then I dispose them. Then I create the same 2 records again. For some reason this time pNext in the second record is not nil. It points to the 1st record. Disposing this weird thing gets invalid pointer operation error.
Randomly I have inserted pData^.pNext := nil in the DisposeData procedure.
Now the code looks like this:

```
procedure DisposeData(var pData: PFILEDATA);
var pNextData: PFILEDATA;
begin
  while pData <> nil do begin
    pNextData := pData^.pNext;
    pData^.pNext := nil;          // <----
    Dispose(pData^.pFullPath);
    Dispose(pData);
    pData := pNextData;
  end;
end;
```

The error is gone.
I'll try to change PVeryLongPath into TVeryLongPath.

Comment: Both of those `Finalize` calls are null operations since 1. `Dispose` include a `Finalize` of its members and 2. `pFullPath` isn't a managed type anyway.

Comment: How is the `PVeryLongPath` type defined?

Comment: The edit to the question and the answer you accepted lead me to believe that you have a serious problem in the code which adds nodes to the list. The only way you could see the behaviour you report is if your link handling code is wrong. Since Rudy and I gave you solutions to the question that you asked it seems that the list building code must be broken. Something doesn't add up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that you accepted Serg's answer indicates that there is something wrong with your node creation code. Your comment to that answer confirms that.

I'm adding this as a new answer because the edits to the question significantly change it.

Linked list code should look like this:

```
var
  Head: PNode=nil;
  //this may be a global variable, or better, a field in a class, 
  //in which case it would be initialized to nil on creation

function AddNode(var Head: PNode): PNode;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result.Next := Head;
  Head := Result;
end;
```

Notice that we are adding the node to the head of the list. We don't need to initialize `Next` to `nil` anywhere because we **always** assign another node pointer to `Next`.  That rule is important.

I've written this as a function which returns the new node. Since the new node is always added at the head this is somewhat redundant. Because you can ignore function return values it doesn't really do any harm.

Sometimes you may want to initialize the contents of the node when you add new nodes.  For example:

```
function AddNode(var Head: PNode; const Caption: string): PNode;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result.Caption := Caption;
  Result.Next := Head;
  Head := Result;
end;
```

I much prefer this approach. Always make sure that your fields are initialized. If zero initialization is fine for you then you can use `AllocMem` to create your node.

Here's a more concrete example of using such a method:

```
type
  PNode = ^TNode;
  TNode = record
    Caption: string;
    Next: PNode;
  end;

procedure PopulateList(Items: TStrings);
var
  Item: string;
begin
  for Item in Items do
    AddNode(Head, Item);
end;
```

To destroy the list the code runs like this:

```
procedure DestroyList(var Head: PNode);
var
  Next: PNode;
begin
  while Assigned(Head) do begin
    Next := Head.Next;
    Dispose(Head);
    Head := Next;
  end;
end;
```

You can clearly see that this method can only return when `Head` is `nil`.

If you encapsulate your linked list in a class then you can make the head pointer a member of the class and avoid the need to pass it around.

The main point I would like to make is that manual memory allocation code is delicate. It is easy to make little mistakes in the details. In situations like that it pays to put the delicate code in helper functions or methods so you only need to write it once. Linked lists are a great example of a problem that loves to be solved with generics. You can write the memory management code once and re-use it for all sorts of different node types.

Comment: So if I understand correctly this will create the linked list in the backwards order compared to my current code. OK, I'll see how to do it.

Comment: @Antans You understand correct. It will do it backwards. If you want the list items in the same order as you presently have, just run your for loop backwards with a `downto`. All that said, why a linked list rather than a plain `TList<TFILEDATA>` or even an `array of TFILEDATA`?

Comment: Linked lists were popular about 30 years ago, before the arrival of object oriented languages like TP 5.5 and Delphi. Never used linked lists since then, and no regrets. As David points out, use a TList or ARRAY of constructs.

Comment: @LU RD They still have their uses. Inserting into the middle of a list is efficient for linked list. On the downside, random access is pretty much hopeless for linked list.

Comment: @LU RD - as David says, they are still useful for specific stuff; for instance for the [FIFO queue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6896666/how-do-you-design-fifo-queue-with-variable-data-size/6898982#6898982).

Comment: @David and daemon_x, yes I should have mentioned that linked lists can have its uses. As I recall it though, it was never used in Delphi rtl. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984916/generic-linked-list-for-delphi-2009 for a 3rd party generic linked list. My advice would still be, avoid linked lists unless there is a good reason not to. And in that case, make sure the use of such a list is well documented a preferably encapsuled in a class.

Answer (score 6):

First, if you free something, the contents of pointers to it do not change. That is why you don't see a change in the local variables display.

*EDIT: declare* `pFullPath` *as* `TVeryLongPath`. *This is a reference type already, and you should not use a pointer to such a type. New() doesn't do what you think it does, in such a case.*

*It would probably be better if you declared it as UnicodeString, or if your Delphi doesn't have that, WideString.*

If pFullPath is declared as a dynamic "array of WideChar", then you should not use New() on it. For dynamic arrays, use SetLength() and nothing else. Dispose() will properly dispose of all items in your record, so just do:

```
New(Result);
SetLength(Result^.pFullPath, size_you_need);
```

and later:

```
Dispose(pData);
```

In normal code, you should never have to call Finalize(). This is all taken care of by Dispose, as long as you pass a pointer of the **correct type** to Dispose().

FWIW, I would recommend [this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pointers.html) and [this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-pchars.html) article of mine.

Comment: If it was declared as a dynamic array or a string, it wouldn't have been allocated with a `New`.

Comment: That is what I said. And well, his comment says "Free dynamic array". I have seen people free dynarrays with FreeMem(), so it would not surprise me if he used New() on a dynarray, or on a pointer to a dynarray. We don't know how PVeryLongPath is declared. He showed the declaraton of the pointer to fixed size array, after all.

Comment: `PVeryLongPath` will be pointer to fixed length array of WideChar.

Comment: PVeryLongPath is:

    type
      TVeryLongPath = array of WideChar;
      PVeryLongPath = ^TVeryLongPath;

Comment: @Antans Then you don't need `PVeryLongPath` type - the `TVeryLongPath` is already pointer. Use `TVeryLongPath` type and `SetLength()` to allocate memory for it as Rudy suggest.

Comment: So a pointer to a dynarray after all. I'm not surprised. @Antans, if you use TVeryLongPath instead, my answer applies: use SetLength() to allocate it and don't do anything to dispose it, the runtime and Dispose() will take care of that.

Comment: @Rudy Your guesswork was better than mine this time! FWIW SetLength isn't usually needed. You would typically just assign to a string surely? I'm assuming of course that OP switch away from a dynamic array of WideChar which is a pretty hard beast to work with. My guess now is that this is pre Unicode Delphi and OP isn't familiar with `WideString`.

Comment: If it is declared as dynarray, you can't just assign a string to it. of course, it would make sense to declare it as string. That would make many things a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend that you avoid using a dynamic array of WideChar which is not at all convenient to work with.  Instead use `string` if you have Delphi 2009 or later, or `WideString` for earlier Delphi versions. Both of these are dynamic string types with `WideChar` elements. You can assign to them and Delphi deals with all the allocation.

So, assuming that you now have the following record:

```
TFILEDATA = record
  Description80: TFileType80;
  pFullPath: WideString; 
  pNext: PFILEDATA;          
end;
```

you can simplify things considerably.

```
function GimmeNewData(): PFILEDATA;
begin
  New(Result);
end;

procedure DisposeData(var pData: PFILEDATA);
var pNextData: PFILEDATA;
begin
  while pData <> nil do begin
    pNextData := pData^.pNext;          
    Dispose(pData);                     
    pData := pNextData;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also initialize `pNext` field to `nil` - without it you will finally get access violation. Taking into account what was already said in the previous answers, you can change your code as

```
type
  TFileType80 = array[0..80] of WideChar;

  PFILEDATA = ^TFILEDATA;
  TFILEDATA = record
    Description80: TFileType80;
    FullPath: WideString;
    pNext: PFILEDATA;
  end;

function GimmeNewData: PFILEDATA;
begin
  New(Result);
  Result^.pNext:= nil;
end;
```

Comment: I think that was the case. When I dispose the records and create again the pNext in the last record is not nil, it happens to point to the first one.

Comment: This is odd. You should not initialise next to nil. You create a new node and set next equal to head and head equal to the new node.

Comment: Creation is like this: `pSomeFileData := GimmeNewData(); for i := 0 to Whatever do begin pSomeFileData^.pNext := GimmeNewData(); pSomeFileData := pSomeFileData^.pNext; end;`. pNext in the last node sometimes is not nil.

Comment: @Antans Although Serg's answer will make your code work, your code is approaching list creation incorrectly. There is a well known, well tested pattern for linked lists. I have added a new answer that demonstrates this. As I said in the comment above you should never need to set `Next := nil`. You should always set `Next` to another node pointer (and I'm counting `Head=nil` when the list is empty as another node pointer).

Answer (score 1):

I think most of your problems are caused by the assumption that `New()` gives you memory that is zeroed out. I'm pretty sure (and I'm also sure someone will correct me if I'm wrong), but Delphi does not guarantee that that is the case. This can be rectified by changing your code to this:

```
function GimmeNewData(): PFILEDATA;
begin
  New(Result);
  ZeroMemory(Result, SizeOf(TFILEDATA));
end;
```

You should always either zero the memory you get allocated for a record, or at least fill all the fields with something else relevant. This behavior is different to objects, which are guaranteed to be zeroed on allocation.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Lifetime-managed record fields (strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces) are initialized by `New`. Other fields contain rubbish. If you want to initialize the whole record by zeroes, you are better use `GetMem` instead of `New` - it is more efficient, or `AllocMem` which already initializes the allocated memory by zeroes.