# LinkedList in Delphi or Alternative

Tags: delphi

I need to linkedlist. I googled but couldn' t find any example about this.

Is there a linkedlist in Delphi or any alternative suggest?

Here is Java e.g:

```
private LinkedList<JPIPDataSegment> jpipDataList;
```

Comment: See [Generic Linked List for Delphi 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/q/984916/576719).

Comment: There's also a TList< JPIPDataSegment>, it's a dynamic array though not a linked list

Comment: https://github.com/pavkam/DeHL/blob/master/Library/src/Collections/DeHL.Collections.LinkedList.pas  (It has too many error in code)

Comment: The DeHL author is not maintaining the code anymore. See also https://delphihaven.wordpress.com/2011/07/31/generic-linked-lists-redux/.

Comment: Spring has linked lists